# Codeigniter - How to get url variable value inside contoller function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

I have URL like this: `http://localhost/sitename/some-post-title/code=24639204963309423`

Now I have one `findUser` function in my controller file

```
public function findUser() {
   // I have tried with $_GET['code']
}
```

and I am trying to get `code` variable value inside this function. I have tried with `$_GET['code']` but did not worked.

Any Idea how to get value inside controller function?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not passing anything via GET here.  You can try `$this->uri->segment(3)`, to get the string `code=...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to get a path segment variable or a GET variable? It looks like you're going for a bit of both.

Natively in CI, you can use `$this->input->get` if you update your url to look more like

```
http://localhost/sitename/some-post-title/?code=24639204963309423
```

(Note the question mark).

Alternatively, you can modify your URL to look like this

```
http://localhost/sitename/some-post-title/code/24639204963309423
```

And then use URI segments like so

```
$data = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
$code = $data['code'];
```

If you do not want to change your URL, you will have to break that string up manually like so

```
$data = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data = explode($data, '=');
$code = $data[1];
```

I would argue the second option is the most SEO-friendly and pretty solution. But each of these should be functionally identical.

Answer (score 1):

If your URI contains more then two segments they will be passed to your function as parameters.

For example, lets say you have a URI like this:

```
example.com/index.php/products/shoes/sandals/123
```

Your function will be passed URI segments 3 and 4 ("sandals" and "123"):

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller {

    public function shoes($sandals, $id)
    {
        echo $sandals;
        echo $id;
    }
}
?>
```

If you are using `GET` to get parameters, you can do like this:

```
$this->input->get('get_parameter_name');
```

Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a URI normally follow this pattern:

```
example.com/class/function/id/
```

More details for Controllers find [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/controllers.html) and for `GET` find [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/input.html)